# Get a link and text using new simple_html_dom

Tags: php, dom

Using new simple_html_dom

How I can get

1. The Link
2. The text(name)

   div class="stackoverflow"
   href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow
   div

I think you use inner and outertext but I'm new to all of this so I thought I'll ask the experts.

Thanks

EDIT:  I removed the anchor's as they where been parsed and turned into an actually link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the simple_html_dom documentation: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class="stackoverflow" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow Div</div>');

$e = $html->find("div.stackoverflow");

$link = $e->href;

$name = $e->innertext;
```

Obviously you can change the html input etc.